# In the south, southern parts

Tags: word-choice

Should I use "in the south", "in the south of Georgia" or "in the southern parts"?

"There are poisonous snakes in the southern parts of Georgia."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's obvious from context that you're talking about Georgia, you can just say:

> There are poisonous snakes in the south

or

> There are poisonous snakes in the south of the country.

It's considered good style to avoid repeating something unnecessarily.  But if it's unclear what "the south" is referring to, you should be more specific:

> There are poisonous snakes in the south of Georgia.

I don't think there is any advantage to saying "the southern parts" - it's equally correct but feels like unnecessary verbiage to me.

Comment: "In the South of" and "In the Southern parts of" are both natural enough. I think it's subjective which one people prefer.